# Getting 'NSUnknownKeyException' after deleting a control and the corresponding outlet in the code

Tags: ios, objective-c, outlet

I am writing a very simple app with just one view controller. However I am getting an exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Here is what I did:

1. added a UIImageView and created an outlet in the code by ctrl-dragging to the assistant editor.
2. deleted the UIImageView cause I don't need
3. deleted the outlet property from the code
4. checked the connection inspector and removed the outlet from the storyboard/InterfaceBuilder.

But I am still getting the exception as listed above, could anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Storyboards / xib files don't always get updated in the compiled binaries when building new versions in Xcode.  Try doing a full *clean* before rebuilding and see if you have better luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you should do a clean of your project, found in the Project menu next to build That way xib files get recreated and often such errors disappear.

Comment: Thank you @Volker, it worked. It turned out to be cache issue. Here is an another thread discussing cleaning in more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4